# Poll list of objects from a file by multiple processes synchronously

Tags: java, multiprocessing, distributed-computing, polling

Use case: 
I have a file with ids in it (approx 500k)
My application reads these files and processes them (processing for each id is huge).  So overall it takes a lot of time and memory for this processing.

What we need to achieve is by expanding the number of processes (run the Java processes on separate boxes/machines) and divide the entire list of ids in some fixed batch sizes such that 5 processes start processing items from the file and pick up the next batch whenever its processing is finished.
eg. if total items in the file are 100 and my batch size is 5 with total 3 processes then processing should be like

- Process 1: 1-5
- Process 2: 6-10
- Process 3: 11-15

such that if Process 2 finishes before other processes then it starts processing 16-20 and notify other about this so that next available process picks items 21-25.

Kindly note due to memory constraints we cannot do it using mulitple threads on single process/host.

Can someone please suggest solutions/references how it can be achieved.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html

Comment: "due to memory constraints we cannot do it using mulitple threads on single process" that doesn't make sense. Multiple threads in one process take up less space than multiple processes on the same machine. You may need to increase the maximum heap size with the `-Xmx` command line flag.

Comment: sorry for not being clear but with multiple processes I meant to run them on seperate machines

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a distributed computing problem. You have a set of "things to process", and want to do that processing across multiple machines. The simplest and most typical way to do that is to put those "things to process" into a distributed queue like Amazon SQS or RabbitMQ (a file won't work).

1. Have one process (and only one) be responsible for transferring the file to the distributed queue. If you can avoid the file entirely (and have whatever is writing to the file just write to the queue), do this instead.
2. Setup multiple hosts (consider Amazon EC2) to read from that queue, and do the processing.

   - Make sure to delete the item from the queue after processing is complete (and set reasonable visibilty timeouts based on how long processing should take) to avoid another worker host picking up the item when it shouldn't.
   - If you want, you can pull from the queue one at a time, or in batches. I suggest setting up a thread pool on each host to perform the poll/work/delete loop, so the amount of concurrency per host can be easily tweaked just by changing the thread pool size.

By using a distributed queue like this, items taken by one host will not be seen by other hosts (thus avoiding double-processing).